# Replacing delimited data frame values with their respective sum

Tags: r, replace

How can I replace "0|0", "0|1", "1|0", "1|1", "2|0" with "0", "1", "1", "2", "2", respectively, in a data frame? For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("0|0", "1|1", "0|1"), B = c("2|0", "0|0", "1|0"))
```

Expected results are the sum of each pair, i.e.:

```
df2 <- data.frame(A = c("0", "2", "1"), B = c("2", "0", "1"))
```

Comment: `\`|\` <- \`+\`; sapply(A, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))`

Comment: @rawr: Awesome solution. I guess in full it should be `as.data.frame(lapply(df1, sapply, function(x) eval(parse(text = as.character(x)))))`

Comment: I'll add to the circus answers - `lapply(df1, function(x) rowSums(read.table(text=as.character(x),sep="|")) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a try.  If you need a second data frame, use `df2 <- df1` first so that you will have the old and the new (`df2` will be the old), or wrap this with `as.data.frame()` and call it `df2`.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {
    ## split the column on '|'
    s <- strsplit(as.character(x), "|", fixed = TRUE)
    ## coerce to numeric and find the sum
    vapply(s, function(a) sum(as.numeric(a)), 1)
})
```

which gives

```
df1
#   A B
# 1 0 2
# 2 2 0
# 3 1 1
```

Your desired result shows character values, but that seems silly to coerce back to character again after taking the sum.  Therefore I have left them as numeric.  You will probably find this to be beneficial later.

**Edit 1:** Alternatively, you can substitute `strsplit()` for `scan()` and do a bit less writing.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) { 
    vapply(as.character(x), function(a) sum(scan(text = a, sep = "|")), 1)
})
```

**Edit 2:** Here's a third method that is kind of neat and doesn't use any nested loops.  We re-read the data as delimited and then restructure it using the `df1` attributes.

```
rs <- rowSums(read.table(text = as.matrix(df1), sep = "|"))
dim(rs) <- dim(df1)
dimnames(rs) <- dimnames(df1)
as.data.frame(rs)
#   A B
# 1 0 2
# 2 2 0
# 3 1 1
```

Or for fun, the ridiculous one-line version of the same thing ...

```
as.data.frame(
    `dimnames<-`(
        `dim<-`(
            rowSums(read.table(text = as.matrix(df1), sep = "|")), 
            dim(df1)
        ), 
        dimnames(df1)
    )
)
#   A B
# 1 0 2
# 2 2 0
# 3 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1_split <- lapply(df1, function(x){strsplit(as.character(x), split = "\\|")})
df1_sum <- lapply(df1_split, lapply, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
as.data.frame(lapply(df1_sum, unlist))
```

Which gives you

```
  A B
1 0 2
2 2 0
3 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use function `gsub` and package `dplyr`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("0|0", "1|1", "0|1"), B = c("2|0", "0|0", "1|0"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(A=as.numeric(gsub("\\|.+", "", A))+as.numeric(gsub(".+\\|", "", A)), 
               B=as.numeric(gsub("\\|.+", "", B))+as.numeric(gsub(".+\\|", "", B)))
#   A B
# 1 0 2
# 2 2 0
# 3 1 1
```